# How to get a URL of a file in a Word in client side using WebDav client?

Tags: asp.net-core, ms-word, blazor-webassembly, webdav

I am using this WebDav Client https://github.com/StefH/WebDAV-Client library, And I am able to put a lock and do all operations on a file. I am trying to get the Url of the file and modifiying that file in word is basically modified that file. How do I do this? I have exahausted my resources but still not able.

My scenario is in a web application, click on file and open that file using Webdav protocal in Word document and when i hit save on the Word document and it saves it using webdav.

My scenario is in a web application, click on file and open that file using Webdav protocal in Word document and when i hit save on the Word document and it saves it using webdav.